# Different output of a const variable in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, constants

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    const int a = 4;

    int *p = (int*)&a;
    printf("%d\n", a);

    *p = 6;
    printf("%d\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

The code gives different output on C and C++ compilers:

```
//In C:
4
6

//In C++:
4
4
```

Comment: It is *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: Your cast hides the warning.

Comment: @remyabel I hope all compilers treat that as a hard error...

Comment: FWIW, I got `4 4` with C. Testing with multiple compilers/platforms can be beneficial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Attempting to modify a `const` value (read-only value) is Undefined Behaviour. The output can be anything, or the program can crash, or propel your dog into space. You've been warned.

**About `const`, constants and read-only values**

`const` is a badly chosen keyword, in that it doesn't mean "constant", but "read-only". "constants" is the name given to read-only *values*, and nothing else. The opposite of "read-only" (here) is "read-write", the opposite of "constant" is "mutable". Mutable is the default in C and C++ (except some rare corner cases, like lambdas). Consider :

```
int i = 4;       // (mutable) Value
int const j = 4; // Read-only value, a.k.a constant

// Pointer to a (mutable) value. You can write to the value through it.
int *pi = &i;

// Pointer giving read-only access to a value. The value
// is still mutable, but you can't modify it through cpi.
int const *cpi = &i;

// Since the value is mutable, you can do that and write to *p2i
// without trouble (it's still bad style).
int *p2i = (int*)cpi;

// Pointer giving read-only access to a value.
// The value is a constant, but you don't care
// since you can't modify it through cpj anyway.
int const *cpj = &j;

// This is legal so far, but modify *pj
// (i.e the constant j) and you're in trouble.
int *pj = (int*)cpj;
```

**When can you do this ?**

The only situation where you are allowed to cast `const` away is to pass a pointer (or reference) to a wrongly declared function (or similar) that you cannot modify :

```
// Takes a non-const pointer by error,
// but never modifies the pointee for sure
int doSomething(Foo *foo);

// Your function, declared the right way
// as not modifying the pointee
int callDoSomething(Foo const *foo) {
    // Work around the declaration error.
    // If doSomething ever actually modifies its parameter,
    // that's undefined behaviour for you.
    int bar = doSomething((Foo*)foo);
}
```

**What can you do not to get bitten ?**

- Ensure const-correctness in your own code. If a function takes a pointer to a value it is not going to modify, make it read-only.
- Ponder your casts. Casts are rarely necessary, and must not be overused : they basically tell the compiler "shut up, I got this". And if you actually don't, well, your compiler won't help.
- Ponder your const casts. **Twice**. They are extremely rarely useful, and extremely explosive if mishandled.

Comment: For the people which English is not their first language, it's worth pointing out `const` stands for `constant`, e.g. a value that doesn't change.

Comment: @user3791372 watch out : `const` does not exactly mean "constant", but "read-only". Only `const` _values_ are truly constant (and trigger UB on alteration).

Comment: You are always allowed to cast const away. What's not permitted is attempting to modify a const object.

Comment: @MattMcNabb edited in a quick tutorial, explicitly stating this :)

Answer (score 4):

It's undefined behavior in both C and C++.

A `const` variable shouldn't be modified, this includes modifying it directly, it also includes modifying it indirectly(through a pointer like in your example).

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers have already covered that it is undefined behavior, this cast here:

```
int* p = (int*)&a;
```

is bad. It hides the warning you should have gotten:

```
main.cpp:6:10: warning: initialization discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type
 int* p = &a;
```